# Fees too high best course of action

Tags: transaction-fees

When I try to spend about 4.7 mbtc I get an error message  : "Balance not enough". I deduce that network fees should be around 4mbtc, which is kind of high. My balance formed from around 15 faucet inputs 0,5 mbtc each on single adress, so I think that is the source of my problem.

What  should I do now?
1. Does "economical" transfer of these inputs on new address gives me lower fees after that or not? 
2. Should I move my balance to other app, or this is not BitcoinWallet problem and any other app give me same fees?

Comment: Some of the wallets have ridiculous fee calculations resulting in WAY too many fees. Especially when moving around trivial armounts these turn into real bummers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, In my case most easy way out was - make a payment from my adress on my adress of all balance with economical fee, which was small enough, and transaction took an hour and half. Then payment for external adress gone with reasonable enough fees.